# iOS: How to reduce the size of FormSheet (Xamarin and MvvmCross)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am developing an iOS app using `Xamarin`  and `MvvmCross`

In my app Homepage I am brining in `Formsheeet` on click of a Sort button.

IN the `ViewDidLoad` of Home Page

```
private NSObject temp;

public override void ViewDidLoad ()
     {
        base. ViewDidLoad ();

        sortOptionsViewController = new SortOptionsViewController();

        sortOptionsViewController.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.FormSheet;
        sortOptionsViewController.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.cover Vertical;

        sortButton.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => {
            this.PresentViewController(sortOptionsViewController, true, null);
        };

     }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        temp = NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver("CategorySelected", FilterSites);
    }

    public override void ViewWillDisappear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
        if (temp != null)
        {
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.remove Observer(temp);
        }
    }
```

And in the `SortOptionsViewController` I am notifying like this

```
 public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
       {            
            NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName("CategorySelected", indexPath);
       }
```

Since Fomrsheet is covering whole of the screen when I click sort button the observerwhich got registered in function `ViewWillAppear` is getting removed during call to `ViewWillDisappear`.

Any suggestions? Any suggestions on how to reduce the Fomrsheet size?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

What is the code that responds to CategorySelected.

Where do you dismiss sortOptionsViewController?

Register the observer in 
sortButton.TouchUpInside

remove when sortOptionsViewController is dismissed.

Show complete code for the two ViewControllers for more concrete advise